# How to make the same alias accessible in all tests in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to make *the same* alias, that is accessible in severel different tests. And the documentation doesn't explain how to achieve this.

I'm trying to do this:

```
Before
 - Generate datetime-stamp as a string: $dateTime

Test 1
 - Test that no order exists where $dateTime is the first name for the buyer.

Test 2
 - Make an order, setting $dateTime as the first name

Test 3
 - Test that there is an order where $dateTime is the first name
```

How do I, in the `before()`-function make a variable that is accessible in all my tests?
... And please note, that since the `$dateTime` should be the same in all tests, then it should be generated once and not in `beforeEach()`.

### Update1

I can see that it is actually described in the "Do not do this"-section [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases). But I don't see how this is 'making my code do backflips'.

---

### Update2

And are there an advantage of using fixtures, if I do this anyway:

```
context( 'Buy product' , function () {
    let dateTime = new Date();
    let dateTimeStr = dateTime.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', month: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' });
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ', ', '--' );
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ' ', '-' );
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ':', '' );


    beforeEach( () => {
        cy.wrap( dateTimeStr ).as('dateTimeStr');
    });


    it( 'Order with DateTime DOES NOT exists', () => {
        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/dashboard/orders' );

        cy.get( "@dateTimeStr" )
        .then( (dateTimeStr) => {
            cy.contains( dateTimeStr ).should('not.exist');
        });
    });


    it( 'Buy product', function() {

        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/product/test' );
        ...
        cy.get( '#first_name' ).type( this.dateTimeStr );
        ...
        cy.get('#submit_order').click();
    });


    it( 'Order with DateTime exists', () => {
        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/dashboard/orders' );

        cy.get( "@dateTimeStr" )
        .then( (dateTimeStr) => {
            cy.contains( dateTimeStr ).should('exist');
        });
    });


});
```

This code works. But is explicitly mentioned in the documention, that I shouldn't do this. However... The documention doesn't really explain why. Flakyness? Anti-pattern? I don't know. It seems pretty smart to me.

Comment: One way would be write the datetime-stamp values to a fixture file in the `before()` and then read the values to any test.

Comment: Hi @AlapanDas - Thanks for weighing in. If I put the values in a fixture, then I can't really see why that is better than what I'm currenly doing (I updated the question with the code).

Comment: Well I have not encountered any issues with those _backflips_ in my code. Cypress docs do not provide an explanation why this approach might be bad.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with the documentation that using an allias that covers all documents is wrong, but the thing you are trying to do is not wrong and I suggest use [Custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Arguments)

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('getDateTimeStr', () => {
    let dateTime = new Date();
    let dateTimeStr = dateTime.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', month: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' });
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ', ', '--' );
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ' ', '-' );
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.replaceAll( ':', '' );
    cy.wrap(dateTimeStr).as('dateTimeStr')
})
```

And use it in the beforeEach

```
 context( 'Buy product' , function () {
    beforeEach( () => {
        cy.getDateTimeStr()
    });
    
    
    it( 'Order with DateTime DOES NOT exists', () => {
        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/dashboard/orders' );
        
        cy.get( "@dateTimeStr" )
            .then( (dateTimeStr) => {
                cy.contains( dateTimeStr ).should('not.exist');
            });
    });
    
    
    it( 'Buy product', function() {
        
        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/product/test' );
    ...
        cy.get( '#first_name' ).type( this.dateTimeStr );
    ...
        cy.get('#submit_order').click();
    });
    
    
    it( 'Order with DateTime exists', () => {
        cy.visit( 'https://example.org/dashboard/orders' );
        
        cy.get( "@dateTimeStr" )
            .then( (dateTimeStr) => {
                cy.contains( dateTimeStr ).should('exist');
            });
    });
    
    
});
```